# Node.JS Express - POST request not working (returning 404) - running in sub-directory on port 8080

Tags: node.js, express

I have 2 node.js servers running;
1 on port 8000
another on port 8080

The one on port 8080 will be an API, so need to send POST requests to it.(Endpoint: websocket/test).
When I try to do this, a 404 gets returned.
It is sat in a subdirectory(ROOT/webhook), so not sure if that is the reason, or if its the fact that it is on port 8080?

Socket.io is working fine and connects with no issues, I just cant send a POST request to this server.

Here is the server.js file:

```
//SOCKET.IO Server
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 8080;
const fs = require('fs');
const http = require('http');
const https = require('https');

const sslKey = 'HIDDEN';
const sslCert = 'HIDDEN';

const options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync(sslKey),
  cert: fs.readFileSync(sslCert)
};

const httpServer = http.createServer();
const httpsServer = https.createServer(options);

const io = require('socket.io')(httpsServer);

// FOR HTTP
// httpServer.listen(port, () => {
//     console.log("Socket.io http server is listening on port: " + port)
//     console.log(__dirname + '/key.pem');
// })
// FOR HTTPS
httpsServer.listen(port, () => {
    console.log("Socket.io https server is listening on port: " + port);
})

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('made socket connection', socket.id);
  socket.emit('welcome', 'Hiya! Welcome');
  app.post('/websocket/test', function() {
      console.log('webhook received');
      io.emit('webhook', 'You have received a webhook!');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost got everything right. Except you aren't telling your express application to start listening for requests. By just changing this code:

```js
const httpsServer = https.createServer(options);
```

to this:

```js
const httpsServer = https.createServer(options, app);
```

Your server should work.

Comment: Added what you suggested, but unfortunately, I still can't send a POST request to the server... I have tried every variation (with :8080, without, full URL, including folder name, etc). and when posting from PostMan, it still throws a 404 not found...

Comment: If i try to access the page via a browser (DOMAIN:8080/webhook/test), i get: Cannot GET /webhook/test. I added an app.get() and it works in a browser when loading the page (then infinitely loads)! but post does not still. And GET doesn't in postman either...

Comment: Then I think you should try to register the route outside of the ``io.on("connection")`` handler. Your ``socket.io`` stuff should still work. Oh, and don't try to access your post route with postman or anything... Since you didn't tell the route to send a response.